# CSS translate transition delayed on mousemove in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have this animation where I want the image to scale and translate based on where the mouse is over the image.

This works in Chrome and Safari but in Chrome it waits for the mouse to stop moving before applying the transition http://codepen.io/mhkeller/pen/ZbdGQb

If I remove the `400ms` transition time, the transition properly updates on mousemove in Chrome http://codepen.io/mhkeller/pen/GpbJrY

I'd like to preserve the transition if possible. I've tried adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` and the `translate3d(0,0,0)` trick but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML (jade template)

```
#pages
    .page
        img(src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajam/pulp/master/imgs/pages/page-3.jpg")
```

CSS (stylus that becomes prefixed)

```
.page
    width 250px
    img
      width 100%
      transition transform 400ms cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1) // This works when
```

JS

```
function Scale(){

  function Normalizer(min, max){
    return function(val) {
      return (val - min) / (max - min);
    }
  }

  function Interpolater(min, max, clamp){
    return function(val) {
      val = min + (max - min) * val;
      return clamp ? Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max) : val;
    }
  }

  var domain = new Normalizer(0, 1);
  var range = new Interpolater(0, 1);
  var s = function(val){
    return range(domain(val));
  };
  s.domain = function(min, max){
    if (!arguments.length) return domain;
    domain = new Normalizer(min, max)
    return s
  };
  s.range = function(min, max, clamp){
    if (!arguments.length) return range;
    range = new Interpolater(min, max, clamp)
    return s
  };
  return s;

}


var settings =  {

    "desktopHoverZoomOptions": {
        "scale": 1.5, // How much you want it to zoom
        "fit": .96, // A value between 0 and 1. Defaults to 1. Set this to something around .96 if you want to cut off the edges a little bit, like in this demo. This setting is useful if you have white space around your panels
        "padding": .25 // A value between 0 and .5. Sometimes you don't want the mouse to have to reach the edge of the page to fully zoom. Setting this to something like .25 will mean you've reached the edge of the zoomed in image when you're within 25% of the page edge.
    }
}

$('#pages').on('mousemove', '.page', function(e){
    var scale_value = settings.desktopHoverZoomOptions.scale,
                fit         = settings.desktopHoverZoomOptions.fit*100,
                padding     = settings.desktopHoverZoomOptions.padding,
                $page       = $(this),
                $hover_img  = $page.find('img'),
                page_width  = $page.width(),
                page_height = $page.height(),
                adjusted_x  = e.pageX - $page.offset().left,
                adjusted_y  = e.pageY - $page.offset().top,
                x_perc      = adjusted_x / page_width,
                y_perc      = adjusted_y / page_height;

        var translate_percentage = fit*((page_width*scale_value - page_width)/2)/page_width;

        var scale =  new Scale().domain(1- padding, padding)
                                                        .range(-1*translate_percentage, translate_percentage, true);

        var scaled_x_perc = scale(x_perc),
                scaled_y_perc = scale(y_perc);

        $hover_img.css({
            'transform': 'translate('+scaled_x_perc+'%,'+scaled_y_perc+'%) scale('+scale_value+')'
        });


});
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing it to a matrix transformation. Not sure why this works but Chrome, FF, and Safari display it properly.

```
$hover_img.css({
    'transform': 'matrix('+ scale_value +', 0, 0, '+ scale_value +', ' + scaled_x_perc/100*page_width + ', ' + scaled_y_perc/100*page_height + ')'
});
```